# Does a transaction's result get pushed to clients in one chunk?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If user A does a transaction of 100 document updates, are those 100 updates guaranteed arrive to listening user B all together, at the same time? Or is it possible that they'll stream in over the span of a few seconds?

I'm guessing the latter, but would be delighted if it the updates all came together.

(Asking in the context of firestore, but would be curious about RTDB's behavior here as well)

Comment: How do you define "arrive all together"?  What problem are you hoping to avoid?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using transactions on the server side to maintain consistency in my firestore databases, and I'm hoping that means that the database will be consistent to clients as well. If a transaction's results get written to the database, that's great, but if they trickle out to user B over a certain amount of time, user B will have inconsistent views of the data until the trickling is done. If, however, the data goes from the server to user B in one big chunk, then user B will maintain a consistent view of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction results are committed atomically.  There is no intermediate state where any client can observe partial transaction updates from the results of a single query.

I'd encourage you not to think about things in terms of "chunks" or "streaming" over time.  That's not really an accurate description or model for what's going on.  Instead, you should be thinking about the guarantees provided by a transaction, with respect to the client's view of the updated documents.  In other words, the actual implementation doesn't matter, just the guarantees.

When a client performs a query, that query may yield some documents.  Which documents it will yield may vary based on the query.  However, no matter which documents come back, the query snapshot will be consistent with any transactions that previously finished.  There will never be a case where a query snapshot will contain some updates of a transaction, but not others.  Bear in mind that the client will not necessarily to get *all* the documents updated from of a transaction, just the ones that match their query, at the moment the query was performed on the server.  This is your guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

For a Firestore transaction all the writes get executed at the end of the transaction. This is in case any fail or need to be rerun because of concurrent writes to the database.

To answer your question I believe all the data gets updated at once and not streaming in over a timespan.

The docs for transactions and batch writes answer this under the transactions section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, you're saying the data goes from the database to user B in one chunk, and not over a timespan, right? (Also, I added a reply to my question to clarify more what I'm asking)

Comment: Yes, once the transaction has been completed, as long as the other user has subscribed to that as an Observable type of data, they will get a new array of your Object model with all of the changes.